# Share Database Connection across modules

Tags: python, design-patterns, pyodbc

I am trying to access a `pyodbc` connection from multiple places within my code.

Currently the user passes in the connection details via command line, and I process them using `plac.annotation`, problem is, I do not know how to share this object across all the project. What I have so far is:

#### A Singleton Class for storing the connection

```
class DatabaseInstance:
    """
    Singleton Class holding a Database Connection
    """

    class __DatabaseInstance:
        def __init__(self, server, database, schema, table, user, password):
            self.server = server
            self.database = database
            self.schema = schema
            self.table = table
            self.username = user
            self.passw = password

        def __str__(self):
            return "{} DB: {}@[{}].[{}].[{}] @ {}".format(
                repr(self),
                self.server,
                self.database,
                self.schema,
                self.table,
                self.username,
            )

        def get_connection(self):
            """
            TODO
            """
            if DatabaseInstance.connection:
                return DatabaseInstance.connection
            else:
                DatabaseInstance.connection = pyodbc.connect(
                    "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER="
                    + self.server
                    + ";PORT=1433;DATABASE="
                    + self.database
                    + ";UID="
                    + self.username
                    + ";PWD="
                    + self.passw
                )
                return DatabaseInstance.connection

    instance = None
    connection = None

    def __init__(self, server, database, schema, table, user, password):
        if not DatabaseInstance.instance:
            DatabaseInstance.instance = DatabaseInstance.__DatabaseInstance(
                server, database, schema, table, user, password
            )

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.instance, name)
```

Now, In my main, I get the params, and create an instance for the database:

```
connection = DatabaseInstance(
    server=server,
    database=database,
    schema=schema,
    table=table,
    user=user,
    password=passw,
)
```

The application needs to access this object from different modules and submodules, but `connection` is withing the scope of a function.

Is there a better way to do it than just passing down this object from function to function up until it is used by the necessary functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't instantiate the singleton in your main. Instantiate DatabaseInstance in your module as `db`, and when you need access to the singleton, reach into the module and use it.

```
import .thatmodule
db = thatmodule.db.get_connection()
```

It is perfectly fine to instantiate in your main and pass it into code that needs access to the database, to answer your final question. It makes for an uglier API, though.

Both are fine. The choice is up to you.

Comment: But I would need to pass the arguments somehow to the module `db`, something like `thatmodule.db.DatabaseInstance(,....)`

Comment: Fill them from that module reaching into a common configuration, or fill them from making main call a new method that stores them when it's starting up. The configuration route is probably better.  `def main(): thatmodule.db.settings = dict(hostname="foo")` property or something.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it, I have access to those params in a `main` function.

Comment: Simplify your singleton code more. You don't need the configuration until you are later asking for a connection for the first time, so just defer using it until then. Inside thismodule, instantiate the class that has the getter inside, and leave that instance in its namespace. Over in main, reach into thismodule, and poke the configuration into the instance so that later when something calls get_connection(), it uses the configuration data for the first time.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it better, Will try to implement it.

Comment: Simplest case. A property is better, and a config file is even better. https://pastebin.com/raw/C34FywJD